# SSRS: Single Value Parameter for Users to Click to Go To Report

Tags: parameters, mapping, report, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for SSRS purposes.

I'm fairly new to this in SSRS, currently I have 5 different reports (rdls)
1. Workflow
2. Outcome
3. Witness I
4. Witness II
5. Negative Outcomes

What I want to do is create a parameter from the beginning that allows the user to select 1 out of these 5 reports to go to. Then when they get to that report, they can run that report's particular parameters.

How do I go about doing this in SSRS? Or any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly... here' is what I would do

1. Create a new report
2. Add 5 text boxes each with the name of your reports. You could style these textboxes to look like buttons I suppose.
3. Set the Action on the textbox to "go to subreport" and point to the relevant report on each.
4. If the 5 reports all take a common set of parameters, then you could add these to the main report and pass them to the subreports, however this would mean clicking "View Report" after setting the parameters before clicking the textboxes, which is not very intuitive.

The option would be to setup and single parameter listing you reports, then a single textbox with an action to go to a subreport and set the expression for the subreport property to a SWITCH statement that chooses the correct sub report to show. The problem with this, similar to above, is that  you need to click the "View Report" button before you can click the actioned textBox. Again not a nice UX.

Hope that made sense, I rushed this a bit. If you need more clarity let me know and I'll follow up when I have a few minutes spare.